# I don't know what I am doing wrong. Python keeps telling me I'm still missing 3 positional arguments even though I already provided it

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to programming so I don't really know where I mess up on this one. Any clues would be appreciated.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f"My name is {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}")
    def greet(self):
        print(f"Welcome {self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}")

class Privileges:
    def __init__(self, CanBanUser, CanDeletePost, CanAddPost):
        self.canbanuser = CanBanUser
        self.candeletepost = CanDeletePost
        self.canaddpost = CanAddPost

class Admin(User):
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
        self.privileges = Privileges()
    def print(self):
        print(f"{self.first_name.title()} {self.last_name.title()}\n Can Ban User: {self.privileges.canbanuser}"
              f"\nCan delete post: {self.privileges.candeletepost}\n Can add post: {self.privileges.canaddpost}.")

priv = Privileges('Yes', 'Yes2', 'Yes3')
cla = Admin('Jan Lancelot', 'Mailig')
cla.print()
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? It will tell you exactly where the issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

In line 19 you are instantiating `Privileges()`, but without passing the 3 required arguments.

```
self.privileges = Privileges()
```

If you want to use the `Privileges()` instance created just above (`priv = Privileges('Yes', 'Yes2', 'Yes3')`), you need to make it possible for `Admin` to accept an object of the class `Privilege` in the constructor, i.e.

```
 class Admin(User):
     def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, privileges):
         super().__init__(first_name, last_name)
         self.privileges = privileges # of type Privileges
```

Comment: Thanks, I only recently begun to learn classes so I'm really confused as to how things work. Thanks for the help.